# why Python pickle is different between win & linux with using os

Tags: python, serialization, pickle

with finishing my poc, i find the difference

```
#py 3.9.6
import pickle
import os


class PickleRCE(object):
    def __reduce__(self):
        return (os.system, ('whoami',))


print(pickle.dumps(PickleRCE(), protocol=0))
```

when i loads the pickle bytes of windows in linux,i get "**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nt'**
";

when i loads the pickle bytes of linux in windows,i get "**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'posix'"**.

which means pickle file with os module cannot cross platform

thank you

Comment: What is a "poc"?

Comment: What do you mean by using the tag `ctf`?

Answer (score 1):

Python pickles *are not guaranteed to be portable*.  A trivial pickle is at best portable between Python versions supporting the same versions of the pickle protocol.  But they are not necessarily even portable between Python versions, e.g. if you're pickling a function that is in the standard library of one version but not the other.

In this case you can see for yourself the difference in the data (there are some nice modules for analyzing the contents of pickles but let's just look at the bytes):

```
>>> p = pickle.dumps((os.system, ('whatever',)))
>>> p
b'\x80\x03cposix\nsystem\nq\x00X\x08\x00\x00\x00whateverq\x01\x85q\x02\x86q\x03.'
```

as you can see there's something in there about "posix" and "system" (this is on Linux).  On Windows you would see `nt\nsystem` in the same place.

This is because the best it can do w.r.t. pickling functions is to store the name of the module in which the function was defined and the name of the function itself, and try to import it from that module.

In the case of `os.system` it is a built-in function that is actually defined in either the `posix` module or the `nt` module, but is also imported into the `os` module for convenience/portability.

```
>>> os.system.__module__
'posix'
```

There are some extensions to the pickle module (e.g. [dill](https://pypi.org/project/dill/) that can pickle pure Python functions (essentially by pickling their bytecode, among other bits).  But this won't work for built-in functions like `os.system`.

Not sure what you're trying to do but there's probably a better way (have you tried [`os.getlogin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getlogin)?